# Use sed to reformat line, duplicate one section onto the begining of other sections on seperate lines

Tags: awk, sed, iteration, ls-colors

For LS_COLORS and ~/.dir_colors loading with a filter (sed?)
Rather than having `"pattern color" "pattern color"`... on 10 lines, I'd like to have `DEF_COLOR color pattern pattern pattern...` on one line.
How can sed reformat a line so I can use

```
DEF_COLOR 31 .tar .tgz .zip .z .gz .bz .tbz .tbz
```

and get the many lines needed in the actual config file format? Like this...

```
.tar 31
.tgz 31
.zip 31
.z   31
.gz  31
.bz  31
.tbz 31
```

Comment: Invoking sed twice is annoying.  I figured out how to do it invoking sed once (I am not a sed programer, and this is ugly too.  I like the perl better at this point.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ cat file
DEF_COLOR 31 .tar .tgz .zip .z .gz .bz .tbz .tbz

$ awk '{for (i=3;i<=NF;i++) print $i, $2}' file
.tar 31
.tgz 31
.zip 31
.z 31
.gz 31
.bz 31
.tbz 31
.tbz 31
```

If you only want to do that for the line that starts with DEF_COLOR (the only line in the example but maybe you have others) then:

```
awk '/^DEF_COLOR/{for (i=3;i<=NF;i++) print $i, $2}' file
```

The above will behave the same way using any awk in any shell on every Unix box so if you're looking for a solution that's portable across all Unix systems, this is it.

Comment: No, not a printing problem... a config-file-is-to-long problem. I want a more compact format.  But thank you for the printf tip.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I thought it was clear, but I did edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I shorted that line... I fixed the output now too.

Comment: Thats better, thanks. I fixed the formatting of the output for you.

Comment: Excellent.  I usually avoid awk even more than I avoid sed (though perl seemed a bit heavy for this little job).  I shouldn't have asked specifically for a sed solution.

Comment: Avoiding awk makes no sense. Every tool has it's purpose. `grep` is for doing `g/re/p`, `sed` is for doing simple `s/old/new/`, `awk` is for doing any other text manipulation and a shell is for manipulating files/processes and sequencing calls to tools. If you avoid awk (or sed) when writing scripts then it's like trying to build a house while avoiding using a hammer or drill - sure you **can** do it but it'll take you longer and have a worse product in the end. Unlike perl and other programming languages, awk has a tiny C-like language that's very easy to learn but enormously powerful.

Answer (score 2):

I like sed, but I don't like it for this.  (It doesn't do field separators well)

Here's a perl version.

`perl -lne '@f=split;print "$_ $f[1]" for @f[2..$#f]'`

- split the line into array `@f`
- use `-l` to get line break on every print
- print every item in `@f` from the 3rd to the last with the 2nd item afterwards

Or, as @tshiono points out, add `-a` to get the array automatically:

`perl -lane 'print "$_ $F[1]" for @F[2..$#F]'`

In general `perl -p` and `perl -n` put perl into a stream processing mode analogous to `sed` and `sed -n` ... but with many more tools available.

Comment: Good answer! If you enable `autosplit mode` with `-lane` option and replace `@f` with `@F`, you can save `@f=split`.

Answer (score 1):

With `GNU sed` how about:

```
echo DEF_COLOR 31 .tar .tgz .zip .z .gz .bz .tbz .tbz21 .tz .zoo .7z .rz | sed 's/ /\n/g' | sed -n '
2{h;d}           ;# save the 2nd line in hold space and delete pettern space
3,${G;s/\n/ /;p} ;# append hold space to pattern space; replace the 1st newline with a whitespace; then print pattern space
```

Output:

```
.tar 31
.tgz 31
.zip 31
.z 31
.gz 31
.bz 31
.tbz 31
.tbz21 31
.tz 31
.zoo 31
.7z 31
.rz 31
```

As @stevesliva comments, I'd prefer to use other language for this kind of task :)

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/^DEF_COLOR */{ s///      ; t x ; :x
s/\([^ ]*\)  *\([^ ]*\)/\2 \1\nDEF_COLOR \1/; t ok
d
:ok ; P;D}
```

1. Only work on DEF_COLOR lines, delete that and spaces, and use t x ; :x (nop) to clear the jump flag.
2. Then s/// to swap the first 2 words (31 .tar -> .tar 31) for printing, but also add a newline (end printing) and add DEF_COLOR color again, so it's still a DEF_COLOR line after the \n. 
   DEF_COLOR 31 .tar .tgz... becomes .tar 31\nDEF_COLOR 31 .tgz... and if that worked goto ok (skip d in #3)(t jumps if s/// worked, but it worked in step #1 too, that's why the t ok;:ok there, so the t here tests only if this s/// worked) (this step is ugly, I'm sure there are better ways)
3. If s/// failed (just color remains, no patterns) delete it all. (line done)
4. ok: Swapping pattern/color worked, so P(print to newline(pattern color));D(delete to newline) and start again (continue shortening the DEF_COLOR line till there are no more patterns)

I'm sure this can be improved, but it works.

 PS: Sorry to answer my own question. (and I think I'll use the perl solution)

Comment: ... I should use the awk solution.

Comment: I think one of my highest rated non-trivial answers is to my own question...

Answer (score 0):

Just making it a script seems the best answer.

```
function EXT() { for x in "$@"; do echo ".$x $COLOR"; done; }
COLOR=31 EXT tar tgz zip z gz bz tbz tbz
```

To answer the question as I asked it

DEF_COLOR 31 .tar .tgz .zip .z .gz .bz .tbz .tbz

I could use

```
function DEF_COLOR { C="$1"; shift; for x in "$@"; do echo "$x $C"; done; }
```